# Symfony2 / Doctrine 2 : Sluggable extension : Access slug value during onFlush or postUpdate Event

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, stofdoctrineextensions

I have a *Restaurant* entity with a One-To-One relationship with an *ImageRestaurant* entity.

I can edit both entities using a single form (ImageRestauranType is embedded in RestaurantType).

*Restaurant* entity has a *slug*, which is generated thanks to the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle), and using the Gedmo\Sluggable annotation.

I am trying to rename the file linked to my *ImageRestaurant* entity using the *slug* attribute (*slug.jpg* for example) each time a *Restaurant* entity is updated and the *slug* attribute is regenerated. I want also to change the *name* attribute of the *ImageRestaurant* entity.

I have two options using the Doctrine events :

1. onFlush event :

I have access to the entities scheduled for update (*Restaurant*) but at this time, the updated slug is not accessible. So I can not update the file and the *ImageRestaurant* entity.

2. postUpdate event :

I have access to the updated *slug* but as described in the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist) this event is not relevant to persistence in database :

> The three post events are called inside EntityManager#flush(). Changes in here are not relevant to the persistence in the database, but you can use these events to alter non-persistable items, like non-mapped fields, logging or even associated classes that are not directly mapped by Doctrine.

For this event, as I have access to the entities ID I thought I could fetch both entities *Restaurant* (the frehsly updated one) and *ImageRestaurant* from database and proceed to file and *ImageRestaurant* update ?

Any ideas on how I could achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. The *slug* is generated for the doctrine event *onFlush*. My listener (subscriber in my case) needs to be executed later than the [Sluggable listener](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/SluggableListener.php]) to have access to the regenerated slug attribute.

Here is how I registered my subscriber ([note the difference between Symfony listeners and doctrine listeners](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14547#issuecomment-186426254) - have a look at Stof comment) :

```
fbn_guide.doctrine_listener:
    class : FBN\GuideBundle\EventListener\DoctrineListener
    arguments: [@fbn_guide.image_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default, priority: -10000 }
```